# Find point of intersection between histfit and line - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, histogram, gaussian

How can I find the exact y-coordinate of the red gaussian at x = 0.5 without using Data Cursor?

[image: <code>histfit</code> plot]

I want the blue line to end when it touches the gaussian. But I need to find the point of intersection between the gaussian of the `histfit` shown in red, and the blue line at 0.5. I can access the data points of the `histfit` plot as follows:

```
C = get(get(gca, 'Children'), 'YData');
C{1,1}

line([0.5 0.5],[0 max(C{1,1})],'Color','b');
```

However, the data points of the gaussian don't relate to this axes. Meaning, x-axis of `C{1,1}` is from 1 - 100 and not from 0.1 to 0.9.

Whats the easiest way to find the y-coordinate of the gaussian at 0.5 so that I can replace `max(C{1,1})` by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `XData` as well should give you the right x-values:

```
C = get(get(gca, 'Children'), 'XData');
```

Alternatively, the values of `YData` should be at regular intervals, even if not on the correct scale (since it originated from `hist`), so you could probably find the y-value corresponding to x=0.5 in the plot.

The point x=0.5 between 0.1 and 0.85 (approximately, from the plot) scales to the point x=53.33 between 1 and 100. If the y-value at x=53 isn't accurate enough for plotting, you can just interpolate the value between 53 and 54 and that should be enough.

Here is some code to that should do the job:

```
XPlotRange = [0.1 0.85];
XDataRange = [1 100];
XPlotToInterp = 0.5;
XDataToInterp = XDataRange(1) + (XPlotToInterp - XPlotRange(1))*diff(XDataRange)/diff(XDataRange);
XData1 = floor(XDataToInterp);
XData2 = ceil(XDataToInterp);
YInterp = interp1([XData1 XData2], [YData(XData1) YData(XData2)], XDataToInterp);
```

Here `YInterp` is the interpolated y-value for the corresponding x-value.

Comment: Since `XData` and `YData` give values on a different scale, is there a way to automate the calculation to get the correct value by interpolation as you suggested?

Comment: I added the code that can do this. I still think that you can get the right x-values from the code (the first option I wrote).